# How to keep track of flask session after a redirect?

Tags: python, flask, webdriver, phantomjs

I'm writing a webapp in Flask and I am taking in form data from users. After they pass in that data, I'm trying to automate the authentication with amazon.

1. So I send a GET with a query string and amazon sends me their login page
2. The user is suppose to login with their amazon account, but I'm trying to use selenium python webdriver to automatically log them in the information they submitted the first.
3. After they are logged in with the webdriver, Amazon redirects to an URL I passed in via the initial query string. And the redirected URL now has an access code that I need to grab and use as a part of the token authentication process.

Here's the problem:
After that last redirect, my Flask application loses everything that I stored in the session cookie. My intention was to use the session to keep track of a user_id so that I could update the user records with the access code retrieved.

So how do I not lose a session in Flask after redirecting to an external login site?

Update (code sample):

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    if request.method == 'POST:
        # user is logged in and added to database here
        configs = request.files['config']
        session_id = b64encode(os.urandom(24))
        session['user_config'] = configs
        session['session_id'] = session_id

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=configs['email']).first()
        if user is None:
            # add user to database with data in configs dict file
            # ...
            return redirect(url_for("app.get_auth_code"))
        else:
            # no need to authenticate user
            # continue work as expected
            # ...



@app.route('/lwa', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def get_auth_code():

    auth_url = "https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa"
    redirect_uri = "http://localhost:5000" +  url_for("app.authresponse")

    sd = json.dumps({
        "alexa:all": {
            "productID": session['user_config']['DEVICE_TYPE_ID'],
            "productInstanceAttributes": {
                "deviceSerialNumber": "001"
            }
        }
    })
    payload = {
        "client_id": session['user_config']['CLIENT_ID'],
        "scope": "alexa:all",
        "scope_data": sd,
        "response_type": "code",
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri
    }

    query_str = "?" + urlencode(payload, doseq=True)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/tmp/geckodriver')
    driver.get(auth_url + query_str)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    amazon_sign_in = wait.until(EC.title_contains("Amazon.com Sign In"))

    if amazon_sign_in:
        username = driver.find_element_by_id('ap_email')
        password = driver.find_element_by_id('ap_password')
        submit_button = driver.find_element_by_id("signInSubmit")

        # Fill in email and password
        username.send_keys(session['user_config']['EMAIL'])
        password.send_keys(session['user_config']['PASSWORD'])
        submit_button.click()
        # driver.close()
        return redirect(url_for("app.authresponse"))
    else:
        flash("Login With Amazon page not found")
        return redirect(url_for("app.index"))

    return redirect(url_for("app.index"))


## This is the function where I lose the session for the same user  
## This is the callback route that amazon sends the auth code to after the user is logged in
@app.route('/authresponse', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def authresponse():
    code = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        code = request.args.get('code', None)
        if code:
            user = User.query.filter_by(session_id=session.get("session_id")).first()

            if user:
                user.auth_code = code
                db.session.commit()

                # retrieve access token with POST request
                url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token"
                payload = {
                    "client_id": user.client_id,
                    "client_secret": user.client_secret,
                    "code": code,
                    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
                    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5000" + url_for("app.authresponse")
                }
                r = requests.post(url, data=payload, timeout=5)
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    print r.text
                    return r.text
                else:
                    print r.text, r.status_code
            else:
                print "User not found"
                flash("Auth code not found.")

    return """code:<div id="token">{}</div>""".format(code)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution to have the user's information persist between different pages when making a Oauth2 request to amazon. I'm assuming the authentication process for other sites will be very similar so I am adding the solution I used.

1. Create a session ID and store in DB or Cache
2. Pass the state of your OAuth2 request into your payload via a "state" field, assign the state to be the session ID

   ```
    payload = {

               "state": session_id,
               "client_id": user.client_id,
               "client_secret": user.client_secret,
               "code": code,
               "grant_type": "authorization_code",
               "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5000"
           }
   ```
3. In your redirect url that the authentication service sends the access token to, the STATE should appear in the query string of the redirect URI.
4. Grab the STATE from the query string and use it to fetch all the user information you want from the DB or Cache.

Amazon solution:

1. https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/login-with-amazon/docs/dynamically_redirect_users.html
2. https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/login-with-amazon/docs/cross_site_request_forgery.html